# Nginx url versioning

Tags: url, nginx, relative-path, prefix, resolve

I've got a service with the url structure:
`myservice.server.com` but have released a later version that I'd like to make available at `myservice.server.com/v1`.

I've got a location regex in my Nginx config that intercepts incoming traffic as it should:

```
location ~ "^/(?<version>v\d+)?(/.*)" {
```

where the `v1` part of the url will be stored in the variable `$version`.

The index file for the website references all its files using relative paths e.g: `scripts/myscript.js`

but for some reason, instead of them being resolved to `myservice.server.com/v1/scripts/myscript.js` its getting resolved to `myservice.server.com/scripts/myscript.js`.

Does anyone know how to set all relative paths to resolve to `myservice.server.com/v1/...` instead of `myservice.server.com/...`?

If it helps, here is the full config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myservice.server.com;   

    location / {
        satisfy any;

        proxy_bind 172.17.0.1;
        proxy_pass http://[docker container ip and port];

        proxy_set_header Host $host;       
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_pass_request_body on;
    }

    location ~ "^/(?<version>v\d+)?(/.*)" {
        satisfy any;

        proxy_bind 172.17.0.1;
        proxy_pass http://[docker container ip and port]$2$is_args$query_string;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;       
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_pass_request_body on;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"using relative paths e.g: /scripts/myscript.js"_ That's not a relative path.

Comment: It might be easier to make a separate vhost like `v1.myservice.server.com`.